# Workflow persistence by single start of workflow for various states of a project

Tags: silverlight-4.0, workflow, workflow-foundation, workflowservice

i am using workflow 4.0, silverlight 4.0,  in my project.

there are 5 sequences considering states of my project which have to be initiated according to a field called status from database. Actually each sequence should not require parameter.

i want to intiate the workflow once by calling initial sequence with cancreateinstance=true. Other sequence must correlate with  the same(uniqueID) and  need to be carry on by it own according to status change in database.

Currently i have to call each and every sequence in a workflow as it is contain correlation parameter.

Is there any solution to correlate the variable for workflow persistence without receive send sequence ? If yes  how could i do this? Anything i can do with InitializeCorrelation from toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

Correlation with a Receive activity is a requirement for your scenario.  There is no way to reconnect the workflow instance to the particular silverlight client app on the server side without it.